# System JS not loading modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

I have a strange problem with System JS when I'm playing around with Angular 2.

Everything works fine for a while, but seemingly random System JS can't find modules anymore...

I get this error message:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/platform/browser.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4891
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/core.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/router.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/http.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/core.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/http.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/src/facade/lang.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891
GET http://localhost:9000/angular2/router.js 404 (Not Found) @ system.src.js:4891
```

Sometimes it's more sometimes it's less errors...

The strangest thing is that after waiting a while and trying to refresh the page over and over, the app magically starts working again!

I use systemjs@0.19.20 and angular2@2.0.0-beta.3 (latest at the time).

Script section of index.html with SystemJS config look like this:

```
<script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
  //configure system loader
  System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true
  });
  //bootstrap the Angular2 application
  System.import('dist/app').catch(console.log.bind(console));
</script>
<script src="./node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```

Anyone recognize this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you can share your systemjs config

Comment: Agreed with @Vldao. Without this, we can only try to guess things ;-)

Comment: I've added the config.

Comment: The problem is that you're loading "system.js" instead of "system.src.js", which is what the dependencies are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your SystemJS isn't correct:

Do you use something like that in your HTML entry page:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

From what I see in your HTTP calls, I guess that there is something like that in your SystemJS configuration:

```
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      angular2: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: what is the correct way then ? (I have similar problem)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot as I don't have the enough privileges to comment and ask for more information. Did you try checking if the file `app.ts` actually resides in `dist/app`?